# Calculate the delta in a ConcurrentHashmap in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, delta

I'm using a ConcurrentHashmap in Java and now I want to copy this hashmap to another variable which runs on a server and so first I will copy the whole hashmap, but then I want only transfer the delta of the Hashmap.

For example, I have 20 entries and 2 entries will change. Then I want to send a message that only the two entries have been changed to get the same hashmap on the server and reduce the overload.

So is there an idea how can I calculate this delta?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use Guava's `MapDifference` for that.

Answer (score 0):

How are you transferring the map to the server?

An initial solution would be to clone the origin map just before sending. If the first time, send the full clone. If not, compare the current clone with the previous one and send the differences. Replace the previous clone with the new one and do the same in the next iteration.